# Transmission of the big $\mathcal{O}$, little $o$ and $\sim$ to the remainder of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_{n\geqslant0}u_n$ and $\sum_{n\geqslant0}v_n$ two strictly positive term series.

Show :

- if $u_n = \mathcal{O}(v_n)$, then:
  $$
  \sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}u_k = \mathcal{O}\left(\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}v_k\right)$$
- If $u_n = o(v_n)$, then:
  $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}u_k = o\left(\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}v_k\right)$$
- If $u_n \sim v_n$, then:
  $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}u_k \sim \sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}v_k$$

**EDIT : I finally understood, am I right?**

$u_n=\mathcal{O}(v_n)$ implies that there are $n_0$ and $M$ such as, $\forall n\geqslant n_0$,  $|u_n|\leqslant M|v_n|$, so by sum, ($u_n$ and $v_n$ positives) :
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}u_k \leqslant M\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}v_k$$
Wich prove that $\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}u_k = \mathcal{O}\left(\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}v_k\right)$

$u_n = o(v_n)$ implies that $\dfrac{u_n}{v_n} \rightarrow 0$ so $\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^*_+, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}, n\geqslant n_0 \Rightarrow  u_n\leqslant \varepsilon v_n$ So for the same reasons, by sum, and quotient, $\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}u_k = o\left(\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}v_k\right)$

For the last one, same method.

Comment: You'll have to work from the inequalities that define $O$, $o$ and $~$. For example, $u_n = O(v_n)$ means that there are some $N$ and $M$ such that $|u_n| \leq M|v_n|$ for all $n \geq N$. Then you need to prove the analogous statement about the sums, considered as sequences with index $n$.

Comment: Thank you. I think I've understood, I edited my original post with my solution.

Comment: You need to specify that the inequalities are valid for $n \geq n_0$. For $\sim$, you'll need to do the same kind of thing, but with $1-\varepsilon$ and $1 + \varepsilon$.